# SQL order by but repeat crescent numbers

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and i'm having a trouble with a query.
I have this scenario bellow:

```
| Number | Series |  Name   |
|--------|--------|---------|
|   9    |   1    | Name 1  |
|   5    |   3    | Name 2  |
|   8    |   2    | Name 3  |
|   7    |   3    | Name 4  |
|   0    |   1    | Name 5  |
|   1    |   2    | Name 6  |
|   9    |   2    | Name 7  |
|   3    |   3    | Name 8  |
|   4    |   1    | Name 9  |
|   0    |   1    | Name 10 |
```

and I need to get it ordered by series column like this:

```
| Number | Series | Name    |  
|--------|--------|---------|  
|   9    |   1    | Name 1  |  
|   8    |   2    | Name 3  |  
|   5    |   3    | Name 2  |  
|   7    |   1    | Name 5  |  
|   1    |   2    | Name 6  |  
|   0    |   3    | Name 4  |  
|   4    |   1    | Name 9  |  
|   9    |   2    | Name 7  |  
|   3    |   3    | Name 8  |  
|   0    |   1    | Name 10 |
```

Actually is more a sequency in "series" column than an ordenation.

1,2,3 again 1,2,3...

Somebody could help me?

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the ANSI standard function `row_number()`:

```
select number, series, name
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by series order by number) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by seqnum, series;
```

This assigns "1" to the first record for each series, "2" to the second, and so on.  The outer `order by` then puts all the "1"s together, all the "2" together.  This has the effect of interleaving the values of the series.

Comment: @Pரதீப் . . . It should now.  I put in the wrong second key for the `order by`.

Comment: It worked for me, i only changed the orderby column in partition clause to "name" and i got the expected result.
Thanks a lot!